# React-Native:How to display drawercomponent on hamburger menu click

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I want to display the drawer component on hamburger menu click instead of dragging from left to right and vice versa.Here is the code

Home Screen
...

```
<CustomHeader title="Home" drawerOpen={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
```

...
Custom Header

```
  <Header style={styles.themeBGColor}>
        <Left><Icon name="ios-menu" onPress={() => this.props.drawerOpen()} /></Left>
        <Body>
           <Title>{this.props.title}</Title>
        </Body>
      <Right />
  </Header>
```

App.js

```
    const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
  // For each screen that you can navigate to, create a new entry like this:
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Categories: {
    screen: CategoryScreen,
  },
},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
  });
```

Comment: yes, onclick it should slide to right

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
<Icon name="ios-menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle');}>
```

and

```
     const MyApp = DrawerNavigator(
      {

      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
        drawerPosition: 'right',
    })
      },
      Categories: {
        screen: CategoryScreen,
      },
    },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
        drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
        drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
        drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle', 

      });
```

[ref](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html)

Comment: ok,how would i slide it to right when the hamburger menu is clicked?

Comment: yes even after changing left to right ,when i click on hamburger menu drawer is not appearing

Comment: Please understand my question,how to toggle drawer when i click on hamburger menu

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drawer navigator from `react-navigation`, use `openDrawer` function to open the navigation drawer.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
```

to close the navigation drawer use

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()}
```

Comment: That's redundant isn't it? What about . . .

onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer}
onPress={this.props.navigation.closeDrawer}